# Expected argument of type "string or Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface"

Tags: php, forms, symfony

the error that arises in symfony is as follows:

**Expected argument of type "string or Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface", "Proyecto\LavocBundle\Entity\Datos" given**

I will not put all code so that it does not become too large , I think the problem is in the Type:

***DatosType:***

```
    <?php

namespace Proyecto\LavocBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class DatosType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) 
    {
        $builder->add('empresa');
        $builder->add('cuit');
        $builder->add('localidad');
        $builder->add('calle');
        $builder->add('altura');
        $builder->add('areaTel');
        $builder->add('telefono');
        $builder->add('areaCel');
        $builder->add('celular');
        $builder->add('email');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
    return 'datos_form';
    }

}
```

***UserType:***

```
    <?php

namespace Proyecto\LavocBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class UserType extends AbstractType 
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) 
    {
        $builder->add('usuario');
        $builder->add('pass');
    }

    public function getName() 
    {
        return 'user_form';
    }
}
```

***RegistroUsuarioType (this is the embedded form) :***

```
<?php

namespace Proyecto\LavocBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Proyecto\LavocBundle\Entity\Datos;



class RegistroUsuarioType extends AbstractType 
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder->add('usuario', 'text');
        $builder->add('pass', 'text');
        $builder->add('datos', new Datos());
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Proyecto\LavocBundle\Entity\User'
        ));
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'RegistroUsuario_form';
    }
}
```

***TablaController:***

```
public function crearUsuarioDatosAction()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $usuario = new User();
        $datos = new Datos();
        $usuario->setDatos($datos);

        $form = $this->createForm(new RegistroUsuarioType(), $usuario);


        if($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
            {
                        $form->bind($request);


                if( $form->isValid() )
                    {
                        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
                        $em->persist($form);
                        $em->flush();

                    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('home'));

                    }



            }

            return $this->render('AtajoBundle:IngresarValores:crearUsuarioDatos.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));

    }
```

I thank you all very grateful for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $builder->add('datos', new Datos());
```

should be

```
    $builder->add('datos', new DatosType());
```

Also your DatosType needs the data_class property set, add this function to your DatosType class:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Proyecto\LavocBundle\Entity\Datos',
    ));
}
```

For newer versions of Symfony2 configureOptions instead of setDefaultOptions

Make sure your DatosType has:

```
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
```

Comment: Thanks , I had not given account. but now another error occurs:

The form's view data is expected to be of type scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess, but is an instance of class Proyecto\LavocBundle\Entity\Datos. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to "Proyecto\LavocBundle\Entity\Datos" or by adding a view transformer that transforms an instance of class Proyecto\LavocBundle\Entity\Datos to scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess.

Comment: FatalErrorException: Compile Error: Declaration of Proyecto\LavocBundle\Form\DatosType::setDefaultOptions() must be compatible with Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface::setDefaultOptions(Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Lavoc\src\Proyecto\LavocBundle\Form\DatosType.php line 36. Forgive me if I upset, I did what you told me and a new error has occurred

Comment: No problem, change configureOptions to setDefaultOptions and make sure you have the use statement I mentioned in your DatosType. Have a read of the forms documentation as well, it has most of the information you'll need to do more with forms. http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html